# Inject multiple datasources to single EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to fetch data from two different tables of two different schemas (logical db) in same database server using innerjoin query +JPA nativesql. How can I inject multiple datasources to same entity manager?

my config file looks like this

```
<bean id="userDataSource" class="org.jdbcdslog.DataSourceProxy">
    <description>Data source for User database</description>
    <property name="targetDSDirect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/cUser" />
            <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="masterDataSource" class="org.jdbcdslog.DataSourceProxy">
    <description>Data source for User database</description>
    <property name="targetDSDirect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/Master" />
            <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entitymanager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
              value="classpath:com/jpa_persistence.xml" />
    <property name= "persistenceUnitName" value= "CP"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="userDataSource" />   
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>  
</bean>
```

Comment: Different schemas of the same datastore is (can be) the same datasource ... i.e you only need one datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the database engines i know do not required these kind of *evil double datasource  tricks*, you can just grant read (or write) access to both schema on the same user.

This way the user will have access to both of those schemas and be able to cross query.

Finally use the `Entity` anotation to define which schema to use

`@Entity
@Table(name = "author", schema = "bookstore")
public class Author { ... }`

Comment: <bean id="entitymanager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
                  value="classpath:com/sipac/jpa_persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CPM" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="userDataSource" />   
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>  
    </bean>

Comment: @harimob402 I don't understand why you sent this xml